# C++ dereferencing a instance variable pointer

Tags: c++, eclipse, oop, c++11, pointers

**Hello,**

im trying to learn C++ at the moment but i'm struggeling with pointers i wrote a class for a simple list with the instance variables:

```
LinkedList *next;
int val;
```

However when i'm trying to dereference and get the value of next i get syntax error. The question is how can i derefernce the pointer correctly? If i don't use the pointer "this".

My try was:

```
LinkedList i;
i.*next;
```

and:

```
i.(*next);
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `*i.next`. Or more explicitly, `*(i.next)` (parentheses are redundant).

Answer (score 0):

When you dereference, then it always applies it to the last pointer you are accessing, so `*i.next.next.next` will dereference the last `next` pointer, still the dereferencing operator is always placed at the front of the expression.